# How to query for paint-order support on HTML elements with @supports?

Tags: css

Using paint-order and text-stroke (or the prefixed -webkit-text-stroke), one can achieve also boldly stroked texts in Firefox and Safari.

Example:

```css
h1 {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px red;
        paint-order: stroke fill;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text With Outline</h1>
```

In Chrome, this does not work, as it supports paint-order only on SVG elements.
Now, my question: how can I query for the paint-order support on ordinary HTML elements?
I want to use `text-shadow` as a fallback, but using e.g.

```
@supports not ((paint-order: stroke fill) and (-webkit-text-stroke: 5px $color)) {
        text-shadow:
            0 0 0.1em $color,
            0 0 0.25em $color,
            0 0 0.5em $color;

}
```

does not work, as Chrome reports `paint-order: stroke fill` to be supported (because it is, but only on SVG). How do I have to adjust the rule to make this distinction and get the fallback working with CSS's `@support`?

Comment: Why are you trying to apply CSS properties [which only exist for SVG elements](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#PaintOrder) to HTML elements?

Comment: @connexo because the text outline looks much better than with any other way

Comment: Such a gap in chrome, also a big deficiency of "supports"... I think the just helpful way is duplicating the element (without stroke) on top of itself.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it seems paint-order for html text doesnt work in Chrome. It does in all other major browsers. But I came with this solution, using transparent stroke and background clipped:

```
background: #B276FF;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-stroke: 40px transparent;
color: black;
```

This works as expected in al browsers and you dont need to use text-shadow. In my case with big stroke, text-shadow didnt work properly